# Отправка по нажатию

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть часть кода которая при закрытии окна сразу выполняет код

```
  $('#modal_window_1').on($.modal.BEFORE_CLOSE, function (event, modal) {

    var job_name = $("#job_name").val(),
      job_note = $("#job_note").val(),
      job_date = $("#job_date").val(),
      job_deadline = $("#job_deadline").val(),
      job_qnt = parseInt($("#job_qnt").val()),
      job_price = parseInt($("#job_price").val()),
      job_dif = parseInt($("#job_dif").val());


    if (modal.options.new_job != true) {
      $.post('/ajax/saveJobData',
        {
          '_token': window.laravel.csrfToken,
          'job_id': parseInt(modal.options.sender),
          'job_name': job_name,
          'job_note': job_note,
          'job_date': job_date,
          'job_deadline': job_deadline,
          'job_qty': job_qnt,
          'job_price': job_price,
          'job_dif': job_dif
        }, function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          updateCards(parseInt(modal.options.sender));
        });


      modal.options.sender_element.html(job_name);
    } else {
      $.post('/ajax/createNewJob',
        {
          '_token': window.laravel.csrfToken,
          'job_category_id': modal.options.job_category_id,
          'job_name': job_name,
          'job_note': job_note,
          'job_date': job_date,
          'job_deadline': job_deadline,
          'job_qty': job_qnt,
          'job_price': job_price,
          'job_dif': job_dif
        }, function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          updateCards(0, modal.options.job_category_id);
        });
    }

  });
```

не могу понять как сделать так чтоб только при нажатии кнопки отправить , код выполнялся а при закрытии окно просто закрывалось без выполнения кода ?

В самой форме есть кнопка Отправить

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myButton').on('click',function(){
   тут код на выполнение
}
```

Comment: Так не работает, заметьте там еще параметры передаются какие то event, modal

Comment: $('#modal_window_1').on($.modal.BEFORE_CLOSE, function (event, modal)
Говорит о том, что перед закрытием выполняется код. Вам надо заменить это на мой код. Соответственно myButton заменить на id вашей кнопки. Я так понимаю код не ваш? Там есть слово laravel, значит он работал в php-фреймворке. А у вас в тэгах laravel не указан

Comment: Если  $('#modal_window_1').on($.modal.BEFORE_CLOSE, function (event, modal)  заменить на $('#myButton').on('click',function(){ то результата нет, форма ничего не отправляет